# External Content Type and External List

Tags: 2010

I have gone through the procedure of creating n External Content Type and based on that i was able to see an External List. So the data which i was seeing in the sql table was shown in the External List.

So now we have the same data in two different location on in the External List and the other in the SQL Table.

Is it really possible not to create an External List and in a Webpart i can call the External Content Type Methods and display the data.

Comment: What if one doesn't have Enterprise, just standard? Business Data web parts don't come in standard Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: 3rd party tools can possibly help with a data replication concept. Finally the data really lives in native SharePoint lists, not an external view on surface only. This opens up all native SharePoint list features, e.g. search, change notifications, workflows etc. For SharePoint 2007 / 2010 on-premise (100% in SharePoint as a feature):
http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/SharePoint-Business-Data-List-Connector.aspx For SharePoint 2013 / Online / Office 365 (without installation, runs outside SharePoint):
http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/Cloud-Connector-for-SharePoint-2010-Office365.asp

Answer (score 1):

*"same data in two different location"* <-- actually you should think of the Sharepoint External List as a **view** on your data - it is not the same data in two locations.

You do not need the External List to make use of the External Content Type. You could write your own web part to make use of the content type's methods, or you can play around with built-in "Business Data" Webparts, in particular check out the Business Data Item webpart:
[image]